# Is there a compact C# port for OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv

By compact I mean one that doesn't require you to pull the entire 600+MB monster of a library with you if you only need some capture/cropping/resizing/thresholding/image arithmetic done. I know I could attempt writing that subset myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. And while there are loads of OpenCV wrappers floating on NuGet, nearly all of those are bloated and/or bugged to some extent.

Ideally the subset of operations require should be determined at compile time. However, as far as I'm aware, C# compiler is unable to optimize away unused methods or classes, even under assumption of Reflection not being used. So no luck on that front, I guess.

Comment: Have you given `Emgu.CV` or `OpenCVSharp` a try? I've used them couple of years ago and they only took like 100/150MB (the whole installation). the final release usually takes much less space since not everything is used usually one or two dll is used based on ones usage of course. in my case it was like 20+Mb or so .So there is nothing monstrous here to be afraid of!

Comment: There are a few packages with Emgu in its name, which one do you mean?
As for OpenCVSharp, it left a bad impression - some basic functions work in a counterintuitive way. For example, when I call `src.ConverTo(dest, MatType.CV_8UC1);` I expect `dest` to be in CV_8UC1 format, or an exception to be thrown - instead, it quietly left `dest` as CV_8UC3.

Comment: I didn't like OpenCVSharp much either, Emgucv looked much better. I guess  I was using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV/3.2.0.2721. by the way make sure you give the posted solution a try as well.

Comment: @Breeze Emgu.CV works well, thanks! Can you leave your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: you're welcome. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you given `Emgu.CV` or `OpenCVSharp` a try? I've used them couple of years ago and they only took like 100/150 MB (the whole installation).
The final end result(your released app e.g) usually takes much less space since not everything is used. Usually one or two `DLL`s are used based on one's usage of course. In my case it was like 20+ MB or so. So there is nothing monstrous here to be afraid of!
I didn't like `OpenCVSharp` much, `Emgu.CV` looked much better and mature. I guess I was using [Emgu.CV.3.2.0.2721](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV/3.2.0.2721). The latest version though is [Emgu.CV.3.4.1.2976](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV/3.4.1.2976)

Comment: both Emgu.CV and OpenCVSharp are wrappers and not "ports". just pointing that out

Comment: @HankTheTank yes, but who said they are ports?

Comment: the question asked specifically for a port. that's why I wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

For simple tasks like you described i would recommand using Accord.net Imaging library from NuGet  http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_Imaging.htm,
very good performance and easy to use, also check out all of Imaging.* namespace http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/R_Project_Accord_NET.htm
Good luck!

Comment: Accord.NET managed to **bluescreen** my Windows 10 (watchdog expired, means the system got completely deadlocked) with just a simple video capture app. Even if it's might be due to a conflict with FaceRig virtual camera device, OpenCV never had this problem (it simply captures black screen in that case).